# I have a list view, i i need to populate a custom row layout with two edit text,two button and chekbox for each. what should i do?

Tags: android, android-listview, custom-lists

the custom layout will something like this
 i need to populate a custom row layout with two edit text,two button and chekbox for each. what should i do.

```html
    ||EDIT_TEXT            ||Button 
    """""""""""" 
    ||EDIT_TEXT
    """"""""""""
    ||Chekbox  ||Chekbox  ||Button
```

My Custom layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:id="@+id/etPhone"
            android:maxLength="15"
            android:text=""
            android:lines="1"
            android:hint=" Phone Number"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:background="@drawable/edittext_bottom_bg"
            android:digits="0123456789"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/mobile"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/etAmount"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/etAmount"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/etAmount" />

        <Button
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="X"
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_column="5" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:id="@+id/etAmount"
            android:hint="  Amount"
            android:maxLength="10"
            android:lines="1"
            android:text=""
            android:inputType="number"
            android:digits="0123456789"
            android:background="@drawable/edittext_bottom_bg"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/money"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_column="0">

            <CheckBox
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:text="PRE"
                android:id="@+id/checkBox"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

            <CheckBox
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:text="POST"
                android:id="@+id/checkBox2"
                android:layout_weight="1" />
        </TableRow>

        <Button
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="SEND"
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

My main listview layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/a8">

<ListView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/lvShow" />
```

That is all. I did not create any class for this i just want to show the row in the list view with a button click

Comment: Have you tried my pseudo code?

Comment: The answer that i send you is a layout with only the most importent stuff for you to know. The rest of the layout you must fill in yourself. Like width, height en maybe weight

Answer (score 0):

Ty a layout like this

```
<LinearLayout orientation:vertical>

   <linearLayout orientation:horizontal>
      <EditText/>
      <Button/>
   </LinearLayout>

   <EditText/>

   <LinearLayout orientation:horizontal>
      <CheckBox/>
      <CheckBox/>
      <CheckBox/>
  </LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to create custom ListView. Follow tutorial https://www.caveofprogramming.com/guest-posts/custom-listview-with-imageview-and-textview-in-android.html and update `program_list.xml` in this tutorial with your xml view as you want.